# Getting empty JSONArray as response after making a POST request using Volley on Android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-jobscheduler

I am expecting a `JSONArray` with a list of JSONObjects in the response that was originally passed in the request body. However, I'm getting a success response with an empty `JSONArray`. I'm certain that the API is working fine since I tested it on Postman.

```
JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DownloadManager.Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonArray,
        ResSuccessListenerForJsonArray(requestType),
        ResErrorListenerForJsonArray(requestType)
) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }
};
```

I'm spawning an `AsyncTask` from the job service to make the request.

Here's a snippet of the response:

```
    [ 
     {
         "id": "902b7fc3-5059-4265-85eb-d00db3594af5",
         "user": "test@gmail.com",
         "package":"com.whatsapp",
          .
          .
          .
      },
      {  
         "id": "902b7fc3-5059-4265-85eb-d00db3594af5",
         "user": "test@gmail.com",
         "package":"com.whatsapp",
          .
          .
          .
       },
       .
       .
       .


    ]
```

This is my response handler:

```
    private static Response.Listener<JSONArray> ResSuccessListenerForJsonArray(final String requestType) {
    return new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e("Success", "Notification data logged successfully");

            if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    handleSuccess(requestType, response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Where is your `onResponse` function?

Comment: Add postman success screenshot. May be i could help after reviewing , what is your expected result from the request.

Comment: @PiashSarker I've added a snippet of the response I get from Postman.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I added the response handler

Comment: I'm getting a response code 200 for the request. When I tried it on Postman, I'm getting a 201 response @ReazMurshed

Comment: My bad guys, was just a problem of malformed url